# Python Debugging - Frame Not in Module

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using Visual Studio 15 with Python 3.5 and the [Python Tool for Visual Studio plugin](https://microsoft.github.io/PTVS/). I want to step into this line of the TensorFlow demo file mnist_1.0_softmax.py:

```
# Download images and labels into mnist.test (10K images+labels) and   mnist.train (60K images+labels)
mnist = mnist_data.read_data_sets("data", one_hot=True, reshape=False, validation_size=0)
```

The code runs fine within the VS15 debugger, with and without break points, but when I try to step into the call, I get the error

> *Frame not in module. The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module.*

I am not a regular user of these tools, so I am fuzzy on how to set up the project so that all of the files can be found for debugging. Since the program works without stepping into the function, I know the path is set up so all of the modules can be found for execution. Since these are all scripts, I'm surprised it isn't able to step into the function.

When I set up the project, I only saw a place to enter the path to the module that will execute first.

What do I need to do to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing the code you're trying to debug into is TensorFlow C++? If so, I'd think getting Visual Studio to build TensorFlow would be the first step. Do the instructions at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md help?

Comment: No, this is all in Python, using the Python Tools for Visual Studio plugin. I added this info to my question.

Comment: Ah, right, read_data_sets is Python too. Hopefully someone who knows more about Python in Visual Studio stops by.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching around and finally found the answer here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/106#issuecomment-100416344

```
Tools -> Options -> Python Tools -> Debugging -> Enable debugging of the Python standard library
```

It solved my problem